# Override Angular Material CSS differently in different components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have two components with tab groups in them. One is a main page and I have overwritten the css to make the labels larger, done using ViewEncapsulation.None. The other is a dialog, and I want to keep it small but still apply some other custom styles to it.

When I open the dialog after visiting the other tabs page, it copies all the styles, which I have figured is because ViewEncapsulation.None bleeds CSS but not exactly as expected.

Is there anyway to override Angular Material styles without changing ViewEncapsulation so that I can keep the two components separate?

Comment: And how the code looks like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution 1: you can put all elements of your component into a parent element with a css class and override the material style into it.(it's custom capsulation)

Note: ViewEncapsulation is none here.

component.html

```
<div class="my-component__container">
    <!-- other elements(material) are here -->
</div>
```

component.scss

```
.my-component__container{
    // override material styles here
    .mat-form-field{...}
}
```

Solution 2: use `/deep/`([deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)).(use `::ng-deep` insteaded)

```
:host /deep/ .mat-form-field {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Solution 3: don't change `ViewEncapsulation` , then:

```
:host {
  .my-component__container{}
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me thanks! I was actually already on the right track but for some reason decided only to do it in one component. Removing encapsulation for both but wrapping everything in a unique parent class works perfectly and prevents css bleeding.

Comment: solution 3 work only the top of element but not work in deep.
example:
mat-form-field-label inside matformfield. How can I do with that?

Comment: `:host` is used to address the hosting element.that is the one that you use to add the component somewhere (e.g. `<my-component>`).So the selector `:host /deep/ .my-class-name` means, on current hosting element, go deep (search in child components too) and look for elements with class `.my-class-name`.(Note: `/deep/` selector is now deprecated).
look at: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to customise your Angular material components and provide your own stylings, I have the following suggestions. You may use one of them.

1) Overwrite the classes on your main style.css (or style.scss, whichever you are using). If you are wondering, it is the one that is on the same directory level as your index.html, main.ts, package.json, etc. You might need to add the !important declaration.

For instance,

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  color:blue!important;
}
```

2) Customising the various Angular Material directive (such as MatPlaceholder) by providing a custom class.

For instance, when we use the MatPlaceHolder, and on the component.html template,

```
<mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Search</mat-placeholder>
```

On your component.css, we can then supply the css properties to the placehodler class

```
.placeholder {
  color: green
}
```

---

Note: 
Alternatively you may use ::ng-deep, but I would strongly suggest using ::ng-deep as it will soon be deprecated.

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog {
  /* styles here */
  /* try not to use ::ng-deep */
}
```

Comment: The problem with 1) is that this will apply everywhere, whereas I want two different styles for the same Material component in different places. 2) does not work for my specific example as the things I want to style are mat-tab-label, mat-ink-bar, etc, elements which do not appear in my html, so I can't add classes to them

Comment: I tried all the above solution and only ::ng-deep works for me because the css of element i want to override is generate on run time.

Why it would be depreciate and is there any alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can use ::ng-deep. Refer [NgDeep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: You should not use /deep/ anywhere as it is deprecated furthermore not encapsulating the class inside a parent will cause it to be applied everywhere.

Comment: It may be deprecated but there is no alternative at the moment for similar functionality.