# How to remove the padding from mat-Item-list-content in angular?

Tags: angular

I have been trying to remove the padding from the **mat list content** that generated in the dom,
but nothing seems to be working!
any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your styles.css:

```
/* Top padding of <mat-list> */
.mat-list-base {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

/* Padding of each <mat-list-item> */
.mat-list-item-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Or using [`ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) in your component.css like:

```
::ng-deep .mat-list-item-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

But aware: `ng-deep` is deprecated, though it works.

Comment: i already tried this but it is not overriding it

Comment: Do you add these lines to your src/styles.css (not your component css)?

Comment: i just added them to the style.css and it worked, can you please explain what was the problem on adding them in the componenet css? thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this part helps: [Styling other components](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-other-components). Though, feel free to accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Or take a look at [Override Angular Material CSS differently in different components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370433/2436655).