# Angular Material - How to change the background color of mat-drawer-container

Tags: angular, angular-material

angular material mat-drawer-container has default background-color like so..

```
.mat-drawer-container {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

I'd like to change it to..

```
.mat-drawer-container {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

I tried with..

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

and `important` like in the following example

```
.mat-drawer-container {
    background-color: #dddddd !important;
}
```

**the background-color won't change**, it's still #fafafa

it works for `.mat-drawer` but not for `mat-drawer-container`

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `::ng-deep .mat-drawer-container { background-color: #dddddd; }` ?

Comment: It works, thank you for that!, I'm using angular material v10 and it still works! I was sure `::ng-deep ` is going to be deprecated because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49859784/12163165)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped. But I'd say be careful of `::ng-deep` it changes the style globally not just within your component, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370067/override-angular-material-css-differently-in-different-components) for other answers

Comment: It works but I noticed that it also remove the background of a mat-expansion-panel, so this solution is not good for me. I hope we find a better one. thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't override the existing material classes - instead, apply your own class to the element:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="red-container">
...
</mat-drawer-container>
```

And set the style on that particular class:

```
.red-container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This lets you avoid the ::ng-deep.

Comment: It is definitely a better solution for not using `::ng-deep` but still affect other components for example, it removes the  background of a `mat-expansion-panel`

Comment: It definitely shouldn't - and if it does it's most probably something other from the styles you're applying - it's hard to say, since you didn't provide a stackblitz with example. Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sctdmq where it seems to be working as expected, i.e. not affecting any children components.

Comment: by bad, IT DOES NOT affect other components style. I take it as a solution! thank you again @TotallyNewb

Comment: This should the the de-facto for styling angular material components. There should a be a section for this in docs too. But, blehhh!!

Comment: Why though? why does Angular Material set a specific background color for this? even if this is somehow part of the Material Design spec, it will cause visual regressions for whomever implements this. bad choice, if you ask me :/
It also requires implementors in existing projects to have to apply custom styling as-a-fix, instead of customization. that's bad DX if you ask me...